# WPF Best way of saving "Background" property for a Grid control

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I have a grid which has a LinearGradientBrush set to it.
[image]
My goal is to save the "Grid.Background" property into MySQL Database and to retrieve them as patterns later.

I have looked up for serialization but the "Background" class is "Not marked as serialzable".

Any ideas how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally use, [XamlWriters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) and [XamlReaders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader(v=vs.110).aspx), they allow you to write and read the XAML in the GUI. Like so:

**XAML:**

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF187F25" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF17FF1A" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF690909" Offset="0.421"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
 </Grid>
```

**C#**

```
using System.Windows.Markup;
```

**Saving**

```
 string BackgroundString = XamlWriter.Save(mainGrid);
```

This string can then be stored as plain text in your database.

**Reading**

```
Grid tempGrid = XamlReader.Parse(BackgroundString) as Grid;
mainGrid.Background = tempGrid.Background;
```

The string "BackgroundString" is then read from the database and Parsed as a Grid. You then set the main grid the same background.

Comment: I spent so much time on this trying to find solutions and never thought of that. Thanks alot !!